# How to forecast one step ahead with a scaled model

Tags: python-3.x, machine-learning, scale

I have correctly implemented a ML model for forecasting; I firstly **scaled** all the input features.

Is it all right to **train** a model with **scaled** features and provide **non-scaled** ones to predict **one-step** ahead, using that model?

For instance, having already trained a model with scaled features:

```
today_s_input_variables = np.array([[159, 500000, 6]])
today_s_prediction = model.predict(today_s_input_variables)
```

Answer (score 0):

It's probably not going to work without some further engineering.

One assumption that many standard supervised learning algorithms makes is that the training and testing distributions are equivalent. This assumption is violated when your features are scaled at training time but not scaled at testing time.

Comment: How could I cope with this issue? I did scale training and test set. Now I'm just trying to make a +1 prediction providing just one more example;